# MYSQL query mutiple fields based on CASE

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, case

I have stored procedure, in the middle of the procedure is a query for an address table.

**mailAddr table** :

```
id | address1 | address2
```

**oc table :**

```
id | address1 | address2
```

How can produce a query that pulls all fields depending if the address1 if NOT NULL?

- if tableA.address1 is not null, I want all of those fields.
- If tableA.address1 is null, I want all the fields from tableB.

This query below is giving me problems:

```
select fc.*
    ,
        (CASE 
        WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c as MailingAddress1


                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.Institution__c as MailingInstitution
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.Department__c as MailingDepartment
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.Address_Line_2__c as MailingAddress2
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.Address_Line_3__c as MailingAddress3
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.City__c as MailingCity
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.State_Province__c as MailingState
                WHEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN mailAddr.ZIP_Postal_Code__c as MailingZip
                c.Name as MailingCountryName
        WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c as MailingAddress1,
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_Institution__c as MailingInstitution, 
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_1__c as MailingAddress1,
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_Address_Line_2__c as MailingAddress2, 
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_City__c as MailingCity,
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_State_Province__c as MailingState,
                WHEN mailAddr.Address_Line_1__c IS NULL THEN oc.Contributor_ZIP_Postal_Code__c as MailingZip, 
                c.Name as MailingCountryName
            END)
```

Comment: Which one is table A and B in your example ? And what are  all the fields ? you only show Address 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Probably COALESCE is enough for you.

```
SELECT id
     , COALESCE(A.address1, B.address1)
     , COALESCE(A.address2, B.address2)
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
  ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: I dont think I made myself clear. If tableA.field1 is NULL, I should use tableB.field1 and tableB.field2, and tableB.field3. if tableB.field1 is NULL then I should use tableA.field1 and tableA.field2, and tableA.field3

Comment: Your table doesnt have field2 or field 3. you need improve the question

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to compare corresponding rows from the 2 tables by the column `id`, use UNION ALL:

```
select * from tableA
where address1 is not null
union all
select * from tableB b
where exists (
  select 1 from tableA
  where id = b.id and address1 is null
)
```